# Bootstrap button tooltip hide on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On my site I have some buttons. When a user clicks the button, a modal opens. When a user hovers the button, a tooltip is shown.

Is use this code:

```
<button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Tooltip content" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteUserModal">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button>

<div>modal</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

This works, but the only problem is that the tooltip stays visible after the button is clicked, and the modal is shown. As soon as the modal is closed, the tooltip is hidden again.

How to prevent this? I only want the tooltip to be shown on hover, and not all the time when the related modal is visible.

Comment: use  $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('disable') in your onclick function

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Fixed it by using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({ trigger: "hover" });
});
```

The problem was that focus stays on the button when the modal is open. Changing the trigger to hover solves the problem.

Comment: This helps, but i still have a similar issue with a dropdown toggle tooltip. On a button with a dropdown, i have a tooltip on the button and when you click it, the dropdown shows but the tooltip remains visibile, tempted to $('body').click( hide all tooltips )

Answer (score 25):

For your whole project hide tooltip

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').click(function () {
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("hide");

       });
   });
```

Answer (score 5):

You should open the modal manually with an on click function and hide the tooltip manually via jquery.  So take the modal toggling attributes out of the button like so:

```
<button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Tooltip content" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button>
```

and then open the modal with your own jquery onclick function as well as hide the tooltip at the same time like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  $('[rel="tooltip').on('click', function () {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
    $("#DeleteUserModal").modal();
  });
});
```

Here is a fiddle to show you this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/y4cqy8mh/)

Answer (score 5):

Try to use this Javascript code, I just tried it, and it worked for me.

```
$(function () {
    $('body').tooltip({
        selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
    }).click(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("hide");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to close the tooltip before an action, can use this:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("hide");
```

For example, i want to close the tooltip before open modal, here my code:

```
function OpenModal() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("hide");
    $("#myModal").modal();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your document ready function use this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
               trigger : 'hover'
            });
    });
```

Comment: Only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use data attributes from multiple plugins on the same element. For example, a button cannot both have a tooltip and toggle a modal. To accomplish this, use a wrapping element.

Comment: I tried wrapping the button with <div rel="tooltip" title="test"></div> and removing the tooltip from the button itself. Same effect.

Comment: Add `data-toggle="tooltip"` don't use rel.

Comment: Sorry, same effect. It seems somehow the "focus" stays on the button bacause it's been clicked I can still see the "glow" around the button in the background when the modal is open.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ trigger: "hover" });
});
```

Comment: Explanation should help.

Comment: While the code given may solve the querent's problem, it would be more helpful to have an explanation of what the code does and why it solves the problem posed. Code without explanation is less useful to future querents looking to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but here is the easiest fix for a tooltip on a button to launch a modal ...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
    <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Tooltip & modal</span>
</button>
```

Put the `tooltip` and `modal` on 2 separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 button tooltip hover and click:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn-primary').tooltip({
        template: '<div class="tooltip svg__icon_c_tooltip_right" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>',
        title: 'Tooltip Example',
        html: true,
        placement: 'right',
        delay: 250
    });
});

$('.btn-primary').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function() {
    $(this).attr('data-tooltip', 'loaded');
});

$('.btn-primary').on('hide.bs.tooltip', function() {
    $(this).attr('data-tooltip', 'hidden');
});

$('.btn-primary').on('click', function() {
    var _tooltip = $(this).attr('data-tooltip');

    switch(_tooltip) {
    case 'loaded':
      if ($(this).next().hasClass('tooltip')) {
        $(this).tooltip('hide');
      } else {
        $(this).tooltip('show');
      }
      break;
    case 'hidden':
      $(this).tooltip('show');
      break;
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div style="margin-top: 20px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tooltip</button>
  </div>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Bondigo. Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could also remove the focus on the button using `.blur()`:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).blur();
});
```